# React functional component is not rendering when updating the Sate after pushing data to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, react-functional-component, use-state

I am trying to create a dynamic input form where user can add new inputs.

**Problem**

The component is not rendering when `State` is updated but when i open a `Model` that exists in the same component that is using a `State` to open/close it, all pushed elements in the array displayed at one time.

I didn't write the code of the `Modal` to make it easier to read the code

**My Code**

```
   const [supply_detail_list,setSupply_detail_list] = React.useState([
        {supplyDetail:'',supplyDetailAmount:''}
    ]);
    const addNewSuppDetailInput = () => {
        supply_detail_list.push({supplyDetail:'',supplyDetailAmount:''});
        setSupply_detail_list(supply_detail_list) 
    }
```

**JSX**

```
<div onClick={addNewSuppDetailInput}>+</div>
    {
        supply_detail_list.map((val,index) => {
            console.log('rendered')
            const detalTextID = 'supply_detail_text' + index;
            const detalValtID = 'supply_detail_val'+ index;
            return (
            <div className='supply-details'>
            •<input type='text' name={detalTextID} onChange={supply_detail_handler}/> <input className ='detail-value' onChange={supply_detail_handler} name={detalValtID} type='number'/>
            </div>
            );

        }) 
    }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react expects you to return a new array when you want to update it instead of mutating it. Try something like this:

```js
const addNewSuppDetailInput = () => {
  setSupply_detail_list([
    ...supply_detail_list,
    { supplyDetail: '', supplyDetailAmount: '' },
  ]);
};
```

Comment: It worked. but how does this push  new elements to `supply_detail_list`?

Comment: its basically a syntactic sugar for `array.concat`. `array.concat` returns a new array instead of mutating the current array. So if you do `setSupply_detail_list(supply_detail_list.concat({ supplyDetail: '', supplyDetailAmount: '' }))` that will work too